# Programmatic access to MathProg solutions in GLPK

Tags: c, glpk, mathprog

I have a problem expressed in MathProg that doesn't seem to be describable using the C API. Specifically, I have constraints between variables. I've generated a MathProg file and passed it to GLPK. It finds the correct solution, but I don't see how to access this solution programmatically. The returned `glp_prob` struct has no rows or columns. I could just parse the solution printed by the solver, but I'm hoping there's a better way.

Alternatively, if it's possible to express constraints between variables using the C API, I suspect  this would also solve my problem. My MathProg code is below.

```
param T := 200;
set b, dimen 3;
set C, dimen 2;
set S, dimen 2;

set Q := setof{(i,j,c) in b : j == 1} i;
set I := setof{(i,s) in S} i;
set E := setof{(i,j) in Q cross I} (i, j);

var x{(i,j) in E}, >=0, <=1, binary;
var y{I}, >=0, <=1, binary;

maximize obj :
  sum{(i,j,c) in b} x[i,j] * c;

s.t. q1c:
  sum{(i,s) in S} x[1,i] <= 1;

s.t. q2c:
  sum{(i,s) in S} x[2,i] <= 1;

s.t. size :
  sum{(i,c) in C} c * y[i] <= T;

s.t. c111avail :
  x[1,1] <= y[1];

s.t. c122avail :
  x[1,2] <= y[2];

s.t. c131avail :
  x[1,3] <= y[1];

s.t. c132avail :
  x[1,3] <= y[2];

s.t. c243avail :
  x[2,4] <= y[3];

solve;

printf "set:";
printf {(i,s) in S: y[i] == 1} " %i", i;
printf "\nnot set:";
printf {(i,s) in S: y[i] == 0} " %i", i;
printf "\n";

data;

set C :=
  1 100
  2 100
  3 100
  4 100
;

set S :=
  1 100
  2 100
  3 200
  4 100
;

set b :=
  1 1 30
  1 2 30
  1 3 75
  1 4 0
  2 1 0
  2 2 0
  2 3 0
  2 4 35
;

end;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some additional GLPK API routines you can use after solving the problem. like

```
glp_get_row_prim(lp, i)
glp_get_col_prim(lp, i)
```

which will return you the primal value of the row/column as a floating point number.

To generate a matrix representation of your inequalities between two variables (for example with the C API routines), you have to reformulate the equations, so that all variables are on the left hand side of the equation.
For example

```
x[1, 1] <= y[1];
```

will turn into

```
y[1] - x[1, 1] >= 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I eventually realized that it's of course simple to reformulate all constraints into comparisons involving 0. Somehow this wasn't obvious to me at the time.